# Codeigniter Active Record join and loop only returning one result

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, loops, join

I am creating a simple forum script using Codeigniter and active record.

I want to use this function to get all the threads and their respective reply counts to pass back to my controller.

Utilizing the below script, I am only getting the first thread (and its number of replies) returned within an array as opposed to all of my threads.

Why is this, and how can it be fixed?

```
function get_threads($id){

    $this->load->database();

    $this->db->select('title,ID,COUNT(replies.threadID) as replies');
    $this->db->from('threads');
    $this->db->join('replies', 'threads.ID = replies.threadID');

    $query=$this->db->where('forum', $id);
    $query=$this->db->get();

    $data=$query->result_array();

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: does each thread has a reply? otherwise you shuold use left join tho get also zero-replies threads

Comment: each thread could have any number of replies. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you left join threads and replies you will get each thread even if it has no replies, remember when you are using aggregating functions (`COUNT`) you need to group rows:

```
$this->load->database();

$this->db->select('title,ID,COUNT(replies.threadID) as replies');
$this->db->from('threads');
$this->db->join('replies', 'threads.ID = replies.threadID','left');
$this->db->group_by('threads.title, threads.ID');
$this->db->where('forum', $id);

$query = $this->db->get();
```

`COUNT` will return `0` if a no replies are found

**Brief Explanation:**

You want to know the number of replies for each thread, then you need to tell MYSQL when stop counting and reset the counter. Or better you have to tell MYSQL how to group your data, the aggregation function (here COUNT) will be applied to each group.
Google 'group by mysql' for further information

Comment: Works perfectly - the difference being the group_by line.

Could you clarify as to why that is required/what it does?

Many Thanks